# Pass data to view controller from model class fetched from facebook login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, ios10, facebook-login

I have created a common class for facebook login, and wants to return the data got after login to the view controller from where it is called or requested. Below is my code:

```
static func loginFB(vc: UIViewController) -> AnyObject
{
    var dict = [String : AnyObject]()

    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: vc) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) 
{

                    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){

                        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                            if (error == nil){
                                dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                                print(result!)

                                let strEmail = dict["email"] as! String
                                let strFirstName = dict["first_name"] as! String
                                let strLastName = dict["last_name"] as! String

                                Constants.userDefault.defaults.set(strEmail, forKey: "email")
                                Constants.userDefault.defaults.set(strFirstName, forKey: "first_name")
                                Constants.userDefault.defaults.set(strLastName, forKey: "last_name")
                                //return dict
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(dict)
    return dict as AnyObject
}
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a completion block and pass the dict as a parameter in the closure.

```
static func loginFB(vc: UIViewController,completion : @escaping ([String : AnyObject]) -> ())
{
    var dict = [String : AnyObject]()

    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: vc) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) 
{

                    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){

                        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                            if (error == nil){
                                dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                                print(result!)

                                let strEmail = dict["email"] as! String
                                let strFirstName = dict["first_name"] as! String
                                let strLastName = dict["last_name"] as! String

                                Constants.userDefault.defaults.set(strEmail, forKey: "email")
                                Constants.userDefault.defaults.set(strFirstName, forKey: "first_name")
                                Constants.userDefault.defaults.set(strLastName, forKey: "last_name")
                                //return dict
                                completion(dict)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(dict)
}
```

Now call it as shown below

```
YourViewController.loginFB(vc: instance_of_vc) { (dict) in
    print(dict)
}
```

Comment: @iphone-6 : Am glad I could be of some help to u :) Happy coding and always welcome :)